# How to clean and print digits in \d{3} \d{3} \d{2} \d{2} format

Tags: java, regex, string

Using Regex I need to format a string, that contains digits, letters a-z and A-Z while also containing dashes and spaces.

From user input I have 
`02-219 8 53 24`

The output should be
`022 198 53 24`

I am using the regex

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\\s.]
```

And java

```
String abc = "02-219 8 53 24";
String hello = abc.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s.]", " ");
System.out.println(hello.replaceAll("(\\S\\d{3})", ""));
```

Resulting in 
`02 219 8 53 24`

Comment: Since it is in Java, try `s.replaceAll("\\D+", "").replaceFirst("^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")` if you have a fixed amount of digits.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bqMYoN

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("\\D+", "").replaceFirst("^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")
```

The `.replaceAll("\\D+", "")` part removes all non-digit chars (so, the string in question [becomes](https://regex101.com/r/bhf0Qo/1) `0221985324`), and the second `replaceFirst("^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4")` splits the number into groups and inserts spaces between them. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhf0Qo/2) of this Step 2.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/bqMYoN):

```
String abc = "02-219 8 53 24";
String hello = abc.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
System.out.println(hello.replaceFirst("^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "$1 $2 $3 $4"));
// => 022 198 53 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove the non digit character via `\D` but you do not need it to format your output String. For this you can directly use the [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method or [printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

```
String input = "02-219 8 53 24";
Object[] charObjectArray = 
    input.replaceAll("\\D", "").chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new);
if(charObjectArray.length>=10)
    System.out.printf("%c%c%c %c%c%c %c%c %c%c%n", charObjectArray);
else
    System.out.println("Invalid input string");
```

**output:**

```
022 198 53 24
```